# Accessing Yellow LED

Tags: android, ioio

I don't know how to open this DigitalOutput. The error is in the line 31 -> `led = ioio.openDigitalOutput(IOIO.LED_PIN);` What's wrong on this?

```
import ioio.lib.api.DigitalOutput;
import ioio.lib.api.IOIO;
import ioio.lib.api.IOIOFactory;
import ioio.lib.api.exception.ConnectionLostException;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        text.setText("---");
        IOIO ioio = null;


        try{
            ioio = IOIOFactory.create();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            text.setText(e.toString());
        }

        DigitalOutput led = null;
        try {
            led = ioio.openDigitalOutput(IOIO.LED_PIN);
            led.write(true);
        } catch (ConnectionLostException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            led.write(true);
        } catch (ConnectionLostException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

LogCat:

```
07-29 16:14:03.027: E/AndroidRuntime(18831): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-29 16:14:03.027: E/AndroidRuntime(18831): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{net.ho.simon.testioio/net.ho.simon.testioio.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Connection has not yet been established
07-29 16:14:03.027: E/AndroidRuntime(18831):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
07-29 16:14:03.027: E/AndroidRuntime(18831):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
07-29 16:14:03.027: E/AndroidRuntime(18831):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
07-29 16:14:03.027: E/AndroidRuntime(18831):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
07-29 16:14:03.027: E/AndroidRuntime(18831):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-29 16:14:03.027: E/AndroidRuntime(18831):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-29 16:14:03.027: E/AndroidRuntime(18831):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
07-29 16:14:03.027: E/AndroidRuntime(18831):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-29 16:14:03.027: E/AndroidRuntime(18831):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-29 16:14:03.027: E/AndroidRuntime(18831):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
07-29 16:14:03.027: E/AndroidRuntime(18831):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
07-29 16:14:03.027: E/AndroidRuntime(18831):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-29 16:14:03.027: E/AndroidRuntime(18831): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Connection has not yet been established
07-29 16:14:03.027: E/AndroidRuntime(18831):    at ioio.lib.impl.IOIOImpl.checkState(IOIOImpl.java:650)
07-29 16:14:03.027: E/AndroidRuntime(18831):    at ioio.lib.impl.IOIOImpl.openDigitalOutput(IOIOImpl.java:332)
07-29 16:14:03.027: E/AndroidRuntime(18831):    at ioio.lib.impl.IOIOImpl.openDigitalOutput(IOIOImpl.java:356)
07-29 16:14:03.027: E/AndroidRuntime(18831):    at net.ho.simon.testioio.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:31)
07-29 16:14:03.027: E/AndroidRuntime(18831):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
07-29 16:14:03.027: E/AndroidRuntime(18831):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
07-29 16:14:03.027: E/AndroidRuntime(18831):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
07-29 16:14:03.027: E/AndroidRuntime(18831):    ... 11 more
```

Comment: And the error actually is ? Paste the LogCat.

Comment: Or try replacing `ioio.LED_PIN` with `IOIO.LED_PIN` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you missed some thing that leads to show

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Connection has not yet been established
>
> you are so busy that you are not waiting for a connection :)

```
try {
      ioio.waitForConnect(); //Note this line
      //You Code Goes Here
    } catch (ConnectionLostException e) {

    } catch (IncompatibilityException e) {

    }
```